# Setup Swagger Programmatically Instead of Config files

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, .net-6.0

I am using minimal APIs and I am using OpenAPI support (Swagger) for my .net 6 app.

The middle part of the launchSettings.json file that is auto generated looks like:

```
 "profiles": {
"WebApplication1": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7087;http://localhost:5285",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

My question is how do set the Swagger settings in C# code to match how Swagger is being set in that json document?

This is the auto generated Program class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        var summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", (HttpContext httpContext) =>
        {
            var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
                new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToArray();
            return forecast;
        })
        .WithName("GetWeatherForecast");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: There are no Swagger settings in the launch settings. Which part do you want to do in C#? Opening the browser on application start up?

Comment: There are.  They are: dotnetRunMessages, launchBrowser, launchUrl and applicationUrl.  Those are the settings I want to setup with C# code.

Answer (score 0):

See this post to get you started, long story short is to look up the existing calls to specify what is needed.

[A clean way to add Swagger to ASP.NET Core application](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/clean-way-to-add-swagger-asp-net-core-application/)